# Is wanting to eat a lot of salt, a sign for something?

Tags: blood-pressure, salt, sodium, cravings

So recently most of my colleagues have been commenting that I eat too much salt and they're saying it's a sign for blood pressure and some says it's diabetes. And I do occasionally have a craving for salt.

Is it really a sign for something like blood pressure as others say or is it because my salt intake is low and my body is signalling me to take more?

I know salt is bad for someone with blood pressure, so in a case like that shouldn't the opposite happen? Does our brain signal us to do things that will actually put us in danger?

Comment: I guess it's a need for higher sodium intake.

Answer (score 2):

Salt cravings can be a sign of adrenal insufficiency or [Bartter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartter_syndrome) syndrome[[1]](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/addisons-disease/expert-answers/salt-craving/faq-20057988), so you should probably see a doctor and get checked out.

If you have neither of those things, then you need to learn reduce your salt intake. It is **not** a symptom of high blood pressure or diabetes. (Some of your coworkers have their causes and effects mixed up.) But it can cause high blood pressure, which you definitely want to avoid.